# I am storing query parameters of users in cluster of few documents for all users in a Firestore collection. Will it affect performance?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have queries related to name, email and phone with type insensitive
So I am storing all documents data of `users` collection in cluster of document with 1000 object limit.

This is my user document in firestore

```
{
  "userId": "unique_user_id_123",
  "username": "example_user",
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "phone": 0987654321
  "createdAt": "2023-12-07T10:00:00Z",
  "profile": {
    "fullName": "User Full Name",
    "age": 25,
    "address": "123 Main St, City, Country"
    "imageUrl":"https://aimaagaeurlefdfl/sfklf/prabhat.jpg"
  }
}
```

My query Document looks like:

```
[{
    "userId": "unique_user_id_123",
    "fullName": "User Full one",
    "phone": 4737654321,
    "email": "user@example.com"
  },
  {
    "userId": "unique_user_id_124",
    "fullName": "User Full two",
    "phone": 2937654321,
    "email": "user1@example.com"
  },
...up to 1000 objects
]
```

I also sync the changes regularly to keep it updated.

Is it usable?
Will it have any performance issue?

If anyone is so humble to tell, then can I know the pros and cons of this way of handling query in firestore.

Comment: What do you mean by "cluster of document"?

Comment: means list of documents with 1000 objects limit

Comment: "cluster" and "list" are not Firestore concepts, so it's hard to say how using them will affect performance. Can you show either what Firestore construct you use, or what code these apply to?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: As mentioned above, the question is a bit vague but if the question is - *will storing 1000 documents in a collection affect performance* - the answer is no, it will not. In general neither will storing 10,000 documents or 50,000 documents or even 100,000 documents. Also, *I also sync the changes regularly* - changes do not require syncing. Firestore does that automatically. When new data is written all observers of that data are notified and kept in sync.